Why does the Fourier integral $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) d \omega$ for a causal exponential signal yield 1 instead of 0.5?
I'm working on a problem where I am asked to evaluate the Fourier integral:
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) d \omega
$$
where $X(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of the signal $x(t)$, defined as:
$$
x(t)= \begin{cases}e^{-2 t}, & t>0 \\ 0, & t<0\end{cases}
$$
I computed the Fourier transform $X(\omega)$ as follows:
Step 1: Fourier Transform of $x(t)$
The Fourier transform of $x(t)$ is given by:
$$
X(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-i \omega t} d t
$$
Since $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$, the integral simplifies to:
$$
X(\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-2 t} e^{-i \omega t} d t=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(2+i \omega) t} d t
$$
This is a standard exponential integral:
$$
X(\omega)=\frac{1}{2+i \omega}
$$
Step 2: Evaluating the Given Integral
Now, I need to compute the value of:
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2+i \omega} d \omega
$$
This is a standard result in Fourier analysis, and we know that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2+i \omega} d \omega=2 \pi
$$
Therefore, the integral evaluates to:
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \times 2 \pi=1
$$
Step 3: Confusion with the Expected Result
While this result is 1 , I expected the answer to be 0.5 based on my understanding of the Gibbs phenomenon. Since the signal $x(t)$ is discontinuous at $t=0$, I thought that the value of the Fourier integral should reflect the average of the left and right limits at $t=0$. Specifically:

For $t>0, x(t)=e^{-2 t}$, so $x\left(0^{+}\right)=1$.
For $t<0, x(t)=0$, so $x\left(0^{-}\right)=0$.

Thus, by the Gibbs phenomenon, the average value at $t=0$ would be:
$$
x(0)=\frac{x\left(0^{+}\right)+x\left(0^{-}\right)}{2}=\frac{1+0}{2}=0.5
$$
My Question:
Given that the signal $x(t)$ is discontinuous at $t=0$, why does the integral $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) d \omega$ yield 1 instead of 0.5 ? Shouldn't this integral reflect the average value at the discontinuity due to the Gibbs phenomenon?
Is this integral representing something other than the signal's value at $t=0$, or is there a different interpretation I'm missing?

"and we know that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2+i \omega} d \omega=2 \pi
$$" - - - Do you?

Is this a homework problem? If so, please add the homework tag to your post as we try not to directly answer homework problems.

Yah, it looks like you answered his homework a little prematurely @Baddioes .  And "Delete" never really works here.  Your "deleted" answer will be visible forever.

@robertbristow-johnson yah, that's my bad. Don't know what I was thinking. It's hidden from OP though, isn't it?

@Baddioes it is, no worries. It is only visible to users with 10k+ reputation I believe (I can’t see it!)

@Jdip sweet, thanks!

@robertbristow-johnson As is well-said, "it a'int what you don't know that will kill you; it is what you know that just a'int so."

You mean "ain't"?

@Baddioes yes it is a homework problem,

@robertbristow-johnson I ain't a good speller, so whatever you write....   :-)

Hint: consider Parseval’s theorem as to what that integral means (it isn’t the value at t=0)

@DanBoschen , it ain't about Parseval's theorem or power, it's about the integral $$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f) , \mathrm{d}f = x(0) $$ or DC $$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) , \mathrm{d}t = X(0) $$ - - I'm doing this with $f$ instead of $\omega$ to emphasize how much easier and better the continuous Fourier Transform is with "ordinary" frequency.

@Baddioes, why don't we undelete your answer?  Maybe you can get hits and rep from it.

lefty, would you please show how you "know" that $$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2+i \omega} d \omega=2 \pi
$$ ?

@robertbristow-johnson I see what you're referring to-- and agree, I am a fan of the $f$ and lost the $2\pi$ scaling stuff.

@robertbristow-johnson I'm fine with doing that, I just didn't want to violate any site policies. As long as you and the other high rep people/mods are okay with it though, I can go ahead and do that.

Nobody is gonna give you shit about it.  This is a Q&A site.  You wrote an A.  It contributes to the mission of the site.

The integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2+j\omega}d\omega = \pi
\end{equation}
not, $2\pi$. This is a pretty straightforward proof. We begin by breaking it up into the real and imaginary components
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2+j\omega} = \frac{1}{2+j\omega}\frac{2-j\omega}{2-j\omega} = \frac{2-j\omega}{4+\omega^{2}} = \frac{2}{4+\omega^{2}}-j\frac{\omega}{4+\omega^{2}}
\end{equation}
The first part is the derivative of the $\arctan$ function, so
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{4+\omega^{2}} = \arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\bigg\rvert^{\omega=\infty}_{\omega=-\infty} = \pi
\end{equation}
since the domain of $\arctan$ is $\left[-\infty,\infty\right]$, and the range is $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. The second part is easily solved by recognizing that $\frac{\omega}{\omega^{2}+4}$ is an odd function, and so when evaluated over symmetrical limits equals 0. So, the whole thing integrates to $\pi$.
EDIT: Further proof of imaginary portion integral
This can also be done via a variable substitution. Let
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u &= \omega^{2}+4 \\
du &= 2\omega d\omega \rightarrow \frac{du}{2} = \omega d\omega
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The indefinite integral then becomes
\begin{equation}
-j\int\frac{\omega}{\omega^{2}+4}d\omega = -\frac{j}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}du = -\frac{j}{2}\log\left\lvert u\right\rvert + C = -\frac{j}{2}\log\left\lvert \omega^{2}+4\right\rvert + C
\end{equation}
Obviously, when evaluated at $-\infty$ and $\infty$, the $\log$ portion cancels out, but we may be left with an integration constant, so we have to show this goes to 0 by the following
\begin{equation}
-j\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\omega}{\omega^{2}+4}d\omega = -\frac{j}{2}\int_{u=\omega^{2}+4}\frac{1}{u}du
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{\omega\to -\infty} \omega^{2}+4 &= \infty \\
\lim_{\omega\to -0} \omega^{2}+4 &= 4 \\
\lim_{\omega\to \infty} \omega^{2}+4 &= \infty
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
So we then have to break up the integral into two parts
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{j}{2}\int_{u=\omega^{2}+4}\frac{1}{u}du &= -\frac{j}{2}\left[\int_{\infty}^{4}\frac{1}{u}du + \int_{4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u}du\right] \\ &= -\frac{j}{2}\left[\int_{4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u}du - \int_{4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u}du\right]= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
